# Is it possible to activate venv from yarn?

Tags: python, yarnpkg

I have setup a project with Python and yarn. I'd like to script the whole process of creating, activating and installing requirements into a venv.

Creating works so far but the activation of the doesn't happen in the foreground so the command prompt does not switch to the venv. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
  "scripts": {
    "create_venv": "virtualenv venv",
    "source_venv": "source venv/bin/activate",
    "pip_install": "pip install -r requirements.txt",
    "start": "python wsgi.py"
  }
```

Comment: You can write a shell script that includes all of these and execute the shell script from yarn.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that.

```
  "scripts": {
    "create_venv": "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv venv",
    "pip_install": "pip install -r requirements.txt",
    "start": "python wsgi.py"
  }
```

The only thing that you can't do is source

```
"source_venv": "source venv/bin/activate",
```

This won't work because source is a bash command and it is applied to the the terminal that it is ran from. So yarn will initialize a new shell activate the environment and close the shell. So that would mean your start may not work. And that is where you may need to do something like this

```
    "start": "source venv/bin/activate && python wsgi.py"
    "pip_install": "source venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt",
```